Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, Lemma 4.38, Universal Cover
enter image description here
Let $X$ be a connected CW complex, $W$ is formed by attaching $n$-cells to $X$, $n>1$.
Note that connected CW complexes always admit a universal cover since they are locally contractable.
My question is, why when the inclusion $W\to X$ induces an isomorphism on the fundamental groups $\pi_1 (X) \cong \pi_1 (W)$, we can have "the universal cover of $W$ is obtained from the universal cover of $X$ by attaching lifted $n$-cells."? As mentioned in the attached image.

I have a concept but can't really articulate it very well: a covering space of a CW complex mainly deals with low dimensional skeleton, as for $n$-cells with $n>2$ the covering can just be itself. So we focus on the case where $W$ is formed by attaching 2-cells. If the attaching map is contractable, in the covering space it is again an attached 2-cell and it won't affect the fundamental group. Otherwise, in the covering space the attaching map will be stretched infinitely long and it is no longer an attaching map of cell by definition.

There are three steps here: 1.) The attaching maps can be lifted into the universal cover of $W$ (this uses the hypothesis). 2.) The space described by Hatcher actually is a covering space (this is purely point-set topology). 3.) The space described by Hatcher is again simply connected (attaching $n\ge2$-cells can only make $\pi_1$ smaller). Is there any particular among these steps that you'd like to see elaborated?

The first step I presume. Is it correct to say that in inclusion $X \to W$ induces an isomorphism on $\pi_1$ groups implies the image of the attaching map must be contractable in X (attaching $n$-cells did not make $\pi_2$ smaller) and thus the lifted attaching map will not stretch infinitely and therefore it remains an attaching map for the lifted $n$-cell?

I'm not sure what it means for the lifted attaching map to "stretch infinitely" or not. The point is that the lift(s) exist in the first place. If $n\ge3$, the attaching maps are defined on spheres $S^{n-1}$, so $n-1\ge2$, hence the sphere is simply connected and the map lifts through the universal cover rather simply. If $n=2$, however, a map from $S^1$ lifts to the universal cover iff it is nullhomotopic. The injectivity of $W\rightarrow X$ on $\pi_1$ implies exactly that, because, as you say, the attaching maps become nullhomotopic in $W$ by construction.

As mentioned in the comment, we only need to discuss the case that $W$ is obtained from attaching 2-cells to $X$.
Due to the lifting criterion (Hatcher'sproposition 1.33), an attaching map $f: S^1 \to X$ has a lift $\tilde{f}:S^1 \to \tilde{X}$ if ans only if $f$ has contractable image in $X$, since the universal cover $\tilde{X}$ is simply connected.
Note this attaching map always induces trivial fundamental group element in $W$, thus if the inclusion induces the isomorphism $\pi_1({X} )\cong \pi_1 ({W})$, we will have the existence of the lift, thus the lifted 2-cell.
